# cron / shedualed task returning nothing

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

Ive got a script running that queries an api and saves the data to a db, i want to query the api every 2 minutes (the max time allowed by the api's publisher)

To run the script to call the api and submit to the db i visit `http://mysite.com/grab-data/index.php` and it runs fine.

To setup a cron task ive check the server path using `echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];` with that data i setup the task under `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/grab-data/index.php` and set it to run every 2 minutes as `2 * * * *` set as the image below.

[image]

Ive gone around and double checked but i cant find why this isnt working, any ideas ? Im pulling my hair out over this one

Comment: Please post the complete line of your cronjob.

Comment: is this the line your mean - `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/grab-data/index.php` or do you mean the script in index.php ?

Comment: Yes I mean the line starting with `2 * * * *`

Comment: Mmmm I've never seen this way of scheduling a cronjob. You may try adding `/bin/php` in *Command* before the `/var/www/`, so you tell the interpreter what is executing the script.

Comment: i found the problem, it needed `php /var/www....` but also running it as `2 * * * *` seemed to only run it on the second minute of every hour - ie. 13.02, 14.02, 15.02 ..ect any idea how to get it to run on every other minute ie. 13.02, 13.04, 13.06 .. ?

Comment: again found the answer - to run it every 2 minutes you would write `*/2 * * * *`

Comment: Well done! I could not check your question till now, hopefully I see you already managed to solve it.